# What are the differences between mutableStateof and livedata&viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am a newer to Android Jetpack Compose. I wanna use the observable data that when the data changed ,the UI would automatically update. There are two solutions that i encountered:

1. mutableStateof

```kotlin
@Composable
fun test(){
   var list = mutableStateListOf<String>();
   LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color(0xDE, 0xDE, 0xDE, 0xFF))
                .clickable(onClick = {
                   //when i click the whole list, it delete the last element of list, and then automatically update view
                   list.removeLast()
            }),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {
            items(list) {
                Text(text = it)
            }
        }
}
```

2.LiveData&viewModel

```kotlin
class TermModel : ViewModel() {
   
    private val termList = mutableStateListOf<Term>()
    private val termListLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<Term>> = MutableLiveData()
    
    fun removeLast(){
     //omit removing logic
    }
}

@Composable
fun test(){
   val list by termModel.termListLiveData.observeAsState(listOf())
   LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color(0xDE, 0xDE, 0xDE, 0xFF))
                .clickable(onClick = {
                   //when i click the whole list, it delete the last element of list, and then automatically update view
                   list.deleteLast()
            }),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {
            items(list) {
                Text(text = it)
            }
        }
}
```

it looks like just use `mutableStateof` is convenient, `livedata&viewmodel` is more complicated, so what the difference ? What are the appropriate scenarios for each?

Comment: This isn't really a StackOverflow question. LiveData is from View view-based UI era. Functionally they are mostly interchangeable. LiveData doesn't have any specific ties to ViewModel more than StateFlow does.

Comment: @TheLibrarian Why isn't it a SO question? It's about programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, there's no reason to pair LiveData with ViewModel. ViewModel can be used with anything: LiveData, MutableState, StateFlow, etc.

State/MutableState is designed specifically for Compose. When its `value` changes, it automatically triggers recomposition. Since it is designed specifically for Compose, it is not very useful for non-Compose applications. There's no simple way to observe it for changes without Compose.

LiveData is more general-purpose and was not designed with Compose in mind. To use it properly in Compose, you have to convert it to State by using `observeAsState` so that it will trigger recompositions when its `value` changes.

(A third type to be aware of is SharedFlow and its subtype StateFlow. These have some similarities to LiveData, but are even more general-purpose because they aren't dependent on Android libraries at all. They are part of the Kotlin coroutines library. To use them in Compose, you need to convert them to State with `collectAsState`.)

ViewModel is a class whose primary purpose is to hold data in memory for an Activity when that Activity is destroyed and recreated due to configuration changes. This is a feature that can also be achieved in pure Compose by using `rememberSavable`. But ViewModel can be used outside Composables and is more general purpose. You could design a ViewModel that doesn't use State, and it would be useful in Activities both with and without Compose.

The name "ViewModel" suggests the ViewModel of the MVVM architecture pattern, but you don't necessarily have to use it that way (the Google authors have stated they did not intend to imply that's how it *should* be used). But if you do, it would be used as the intermediate layer between your UI and your data sources/repositories and should probably avoid UI-opinionated types like State/MutableState.

Comment: Could I see a source for where the google authors talk about not intending to say you should/need to use it that way?

Comment: @ryankuck Found it: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/b908fr/comment/ek2cm50/

Comment: This is really helpful to know about, thanks!

Comment: I got it, State/MutableState is special for Compose , while LiveData is more general-purpose ,whatever for or not for Compose. ViewModel is something with Lifecycle, and it  can be used  for anything besides LiveData .Thanks, I need more practice to understand them.